# How to draw a line on a canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.3

I've read some tutorials on the internet but I can't seem to find anything that shows me how to draw a line

Can anyone help?

I tried doing

```
p = Canvas(height = 600, width = 800).place(x=0,y=0)
p.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
```

and, unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, as you are neither showing us your complete code nor stating what exactly "did not work". It seems you already found how to draw a rectangle, and the same tutorial should also have had something about drawing lines, like [the one linked in the comments](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

Since that seemed not to help you, maybe the problem is that you are using Python 3, where the `Tkinter` package was renamed to `tkinter`. This example should work for you:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(10):
    canvas.create_line(50 * i, 0, 50 * i, 400)
    canvas.create_line(0, 50 * i, 400, 50 * i)
canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, fill="blue")
canvas.create_line(50, 100, 250, 200, fill="red", width=10)

root.mainloop()
```

---

*Addendum:*
I just noticed two actual problems with your code:

- By doing `p = Canvas(height = 600, width = 800).place(x=0,y=0)`, the variable `p` will *not* be assigned the `Canvas`, but the return value of `place`, i.e. `None`.
- Also, the constructor should include the parent element you want to add the `Canvas` to (`root` in my example).

Here is a [very thorough introduction to all of Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html), and particularly the Canvas element.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. This error pops up however

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'


That's the same error that occurred when I used the line of code I said in my main post.

Comment: Apologies. I retract my earlier statement. It does work and I had used my laptop whilst using that code, which had the wrong version of Python, ergo it did not work. It works on my main computer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, another question.

I see the parameters in the canvas.create_line part of the code, what do they mean?

Comment: @monkey334 I just noticed what's the actual problem in your code. See my edit. Things like this are not easy to spot, that's why you should always include the error message so you can get better help sooner. Anyway, glad to hear that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_canvas.php

Your answer how to draw any line using canvas.

Great source for learning tkinter. 
I hope it useful for you, like I do

```
from tkinter import *    
canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 150

def paint( event ):
   python_green = "#476042"
   x1, y1 = ( event.x - 1 ), ( event.y - 1 )
   x2, y2 = ( event.x + 1 ), ( event.y + 1 )
   w.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = python_green )

master = Tk()
master.title( "Painting using Ovals" )
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
w.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )

message = Label( master, text = "Press and Drag the mouse to draw" )
message.pack( side = BOTTOM )

mainloop()
```

I just copied from the site.